# Set class on letters in Pangram

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to set the correct class on a set off elements (each letter in the alphabet). Each element has id #alpha_0 to #alpha_25. If a letter in input occurs one time, set that letter green. If the letter occurs more than once, set it red. If it dosen't occur, then nothing (black)

The code below is just something not working that I whipped up.

```
var isPangram = function() {
 var s = $('#input').val().toLowerCase();
 console.log(s);
 var alpha = letters[getAlphabet()].join('');
 console.log(alpha);
 var len = alpha.length;
 for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  if (s.indexOf(alpha.charAt(i)) != -1) {
   if ($('#alpha_'+i).hasClass('green')) {
    // already matched, go red
   } else {
    // not matched, go green
   }
  } else {
   // no match
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it's easiest if you quickly find out the counts for each letter first, then set the classes.

```
(function($) {
  function getLetterCount(text) {
    var alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    var alphabetSet = alphabet.split('');

    var letterCount = {};
    $.each(alphabetSet, function() {
      letterCount[this] = 0;
    });

    var cleanText = text.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]/g, '');

    $.each(cleanText.split(''), function() {
      letterCount[this]++;
    });

    return letterCount;
  }

  function setLetterClasses(letterCounts) {
    $('.letter').removeClass('green').removeClass('red');

    $.each(letterCounts, function(letter, count) {
      if (count > 0) {
        $('#alpha_' . (letter.charCodeAt(0) - 'a'.charCodeAt(0))).addClass(count > 1 ? 'red' : 'green');
      }
    });
  }

  function isPangram() {
    var text = $('#input').val();
    var letterCount = getLetterCount(text);

    setLetterClasses(letterCount);
  }
})(jQuery);
```